# Sólo se ve la primera vista añadida en un bucle for

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

**CONTEXTO**

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que, en un determinado momento, añade una serie de imágenes a la pantalla en posiciones aleatorias. Esas imágenes se encuentran en una base de datos SQLite.

---

**FUNCIONAMIENTO**

En la Actividad principal tengo un bucle `for` que recorre cada entidad con su respectiva imagen. Dentro de dicho bucle, obtengo unas coordenadas aleatorias de la pantalla, y junto con la imagen obtenida de la entidad de la iteración actual dibujo una `View` personalizada en las coordenadas recibidas.

---

**PROBLEMA**

El bucle itera por las 5 imágenes que tengo en la base de datos, obtiene las coordenadas y las imágenes correctamente, y tampoco genera ningún error. Sin embargo, aunque realiza el `addView` en todas las iteraciones, en el layout principal sólo me muestra la imagen correspondiente a la primera iteración.

---

**SNIPPETS**

Método de la actividad principal:

```
// Método que establece el estado inicial de la aplicación
// TODO: Sólo se ve la cereza
private void estadoInicial()
{
    // Recorremos cada fruta obtenida
    for (int i = 1; i < this.contenedorFrutasOriginal.size(); i++)
    {
        // Obtenemos la fruta de la iteración actual
        DTOFruta frutaActual = this.contenedorFrutasOriginal.get(i);

        // Obtenemos una posición aleatoria en la pantalla
        DTOPunto posicionAleatoria = this.objLogicaVistas.ObtenerCoordenadaAleatoria(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay());


        // Creamos una imagen a partir de la fruta
        DTOImagen imagenFruta = new DTOImagen(this, new Paint(),
                                              frutaActual.getImagen(), posicionAleatoria);

        // Añadimos la imagen a la pantalla
        this.layoutPrincipal.addView(imagenFruta);
    }
}
```

Método que obtiene una coordenada aleatoria en la pantalla:

```
// Método que obtiene una coordenada aleatoria en la pantalla recibida
public DTOPunto ObtenerCoordenadaAleatoria(Display pantalla)
{
    // Obtenemos el tamaño de la pantalla
    Point tamanoPantalla = new Point();
    pantalla.getSize(tamanoPantalla);

    // Obtenemos unos valores para los ejes x e y aleatorios
    float xAleatorio = new Random().nextFloat() * tamanoPantalla.x;
    float yAleatorio = new Random().nextFloat() * tamanoPantalla.y;

    // Creamos el punto aleatorio a partir de los valores obtenidos
    return new DTOPunto(xAleatorio, yAleatorio);
}
```

Clase de la imagen que se dibuja en pantalla:

```
// Clase que representa una vista con una imagen
@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
public class DTOImagen extends View
{
// Atributos
private Paint brocha;
private byte[] imagen;
private DTOPunto coordenadas;

// Controladores
private boolean arrastrando;


// Propiedades
public Bitmap getImagenBitmap()
{
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.imagen, 0, this.imagen.length);
}




// Constructor
public DTOImagen(Context context, Paint brocha, byte[] imagen, DTOPunto coordenadas)
{
    super(context);

    // Obtenemos los datos de la imagen
    this.brocha = brocha;
    if (imagen != null)
    {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }
    this.coordenadas = coordenadas;

    // Asignamos los controladores de la imagen
    this.arrastrando = false;
}




// Método que controla las acciones a realizar al tocar la vista en pantalla
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // Comprobamos el evento realizado
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        // Se ha tocado la pantalla
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Obtenemos el hitbox de la vista
            RectF hitbox = this.obtenerHitbox();

            // Comprobamos si se ha tocado dentro del hitbox de la vista
            if (hitbox.contains(event.getX(), event.getY()))
            {
                // La vista se va a arrastrar
                this.arrastrando = true;
            }
            break;

        // Se está arrastrando la vista
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Comprobamos si se está arrastrando la vista
            if (this.arrastrando)
            {
                // Actualizamos las coordenadas de la vista
                this.coordenadas.setX(event.getX());
                this.coordenadas.setY(event.getY());

                // Invalidamos la vista para que se redibuje
                this.invalidate();
            }
            break;

        // Se ha dejado de tocar la vista
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // La imagen se deja de arrastrar
            this.arrastrando = false;
            break;
    }

    return true;
}


// Método que dibuja la vista
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    // Comprobamos que haya imagen
    if (this.imagen != null)
    {
        // Dibujamos la imagen en las coordenadas correspondientes
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.getImagenBitmap(), this.coordenadas.getX(),
                          this.coordenadas.getY(), this.brocha);
    }
}




// Método que obtiene el hitbox de una imagen
private RectF obtenerHitbox()
{
    // Obtenemos las mitades de la altura y ancho de la imagen
    float ancho = this.getImagenBitmap().getWidth();
    float altura = this.getImagenBitmap().getHeight();

    // Obtenemos las paredes de la vista
    float paredIzquierda = this.coordenadas.getX();
    float paredDerecha = this.coordenadas.getX() + ancho;
    float paredArriba = this.coordenadas.getY();
    float paredAbajo = this.coordenadas.getY() + altura;

    // Hitbox de la vista
    return new RectF(paredIzquierda, paredArriba, paredDerecha, paredAbajo);
}
}
```

PD: `DTOPunto` es una clase que representa un punto en 2 dimensiones, sólo tiene 2 `float`, para el valor en el eje X y en el eje Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser que el problema era que el layout era un `LinearLayout`. Las imagenes estaban en el layout añadidas, pero ocupaban demasiado espacio y no se podían superponer.
Sin embargo, como quería ver todas las imagenes sin hacer scroll, cambié el layout a `ConstraintLayout`.
Ahora todas las imagenes se ven correctamente.